# Is it possbile to work locally by training a tensroflow model using data from google cloud storage without uploading it?

Tags: r, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to use locally in R a tensorflow model using tfdatasets and cloudML using training data available in Google cloud storage without uploading it. AS far as I know the package "tfdtasets" should use gs:// URLs directly with gs_data_dir().

If I specify in TSScript.R:

```
data_dir <- gs_data_dir(gs://my-gcp-project/data/)
```

When I run cloud_train(TSScript.R) I get the error:

```
Error: 'gs://my-gpc-project/data/train.data.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudml-model')
```

Here my questions:

1. Is it somehow possible to do it but I am doing some mistakes in my script?
2. If not, do I need to install R in the cloud and working from there directly?
3. would it possible maybe training data from bigTable without uploading it locally?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, just to clarify are you hoping to:
1) Train your model locally with data hosted in the cloud?
or
2) Download the data locally then train locally with that data?

Comment: Hi, I mean 1). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For 1) I think you might be looking for tf.gfile()
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile

Example of use: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/keras/trainer/model.py#L154

Hope this helps!

For 2) If you want to do this, you should look at Custom Containers. https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-containers-training

For 3) I'm not familiar with BigTable, but my guess is you would have to query that data you need and manually pull it locally. I don't think TF.gfile supports BigTable only GCS.

Comment: Thanks. For 1) there is nothing like tf.gFile (as far I know) in R.
2) Yes, I could work but doesn't fit in my implementation. By the way, it is not clear if it worth in terms of costs.
3) Yes, you have to load it locally. For that reason it make no sense here. BigQuery/BigTable could be too expensive. It depends on the use case.

Comment: 1) Yea, I can't see anything on https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/tfdatasets/articles/introduction.html#reading-datasets that lets you read from GCS.

2/3) Yea it definitely comes down to your use case / cost